# Truncated output when running Powershell command in a loop

Tags: windows, powershell

I wrote the following function as a rudimentary way of implementing basic functionality of the *nix `watch` command within Powershell:

```
function watch {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]
        $command,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][int]
        $n = 2
    )

    while($true) {
        clear
        Write-Output (iex $command)
        sleep $n
    }
}
```

When working with cmdlets that return Powershell objects, I get strange behavior. For example if I run `watch 'get-command ls', on the first iteration I get the following formatted output of the object:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
```

But on the second and subsequent iterations, it truncates the object property headers (and any description above it in certain other commands):

```
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
```

I'm curious as to why this behavior happens, and how I can make the output identical to the first iteration for all subsequent iterations. I am running this in Powershell 5.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: Because `Format-Table` to which you implicitly pipe output does not know that you clear screen, and it just **continue** to print table, not printing new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're mashing up `Write-Output` which writes to the pipeline, and `clear` which is properly named `Clear-Host` and clears the local terminal, and knows nothing of the pipeline. It goes better with `Write-Host`.

Since your function loops eternally, the pipeline output never finishes, so what you would get get is this endless list with one set of headings:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
```

but you clear the /display/ in the middle of the list, so it carries on printing the subsequent items without the headings.

If you explicitly write to `Format-Table` in your command you can get the headings repeated:

```
watch { Get-Alias ls | Format-Table }
```

Comment: I actually got the same behavior without combining write-output and iex, I combined write-output thinking it might fix the issue, but still got the same behavior. I'll give adding format-table a shot

Comment: Good news, Format-Table was exactly what I needed. Thanks!